# Pass a list of variables through is.na when conditionally mutating with case_when

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am working with survey data where I need to identify whether responses were not applicable or simply skipped.

- `x1` and `x2` are my primary response questions. x3 is only filled out when someone indicates if `x1` and `x2` are not applicable.
- I want row 1 and row 2 to equal 0 as `x1` and `x2` were not applicable, and I want row 4 to equal 1 as `x1` and `x2` was correctly reported as "None of the above."
- Row 3 is the truly missing observation as neither `x1`, `x2`, or `x3` were answered.

My code below works, but **is there a simplier way where I can just refer to my `list` variable rather than writing a lengthy AND statement using `x1` and `x2`?** I have simplified this example as my full dataset has 10+ `x` variables.

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- tibble(x1 = c("Yes", "No", NA, NA), x2 = c("Yes", "Yes", NA, NA), x3 = c(NA, NA, NA, "None of the above"))
list <- c("x1", "x2")

df3 %>% 
  mutate(
    x3 = coalesce(as.integer(x3 == "None of the above"), 0),
    x3 = case_when(
      x3 == 1 ~ 1,
      is.na(x1) & is.na(x2) ~ NA_real_,
      TRUE ~ 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal revision is replacing `is.na(x1) & is.na(x2)` with `if_all(..., is.na)`, i.e.

```r
df3 %>% 
  mutate(
    x3 = coalesce(as.integer(x3 == "None of the above"), 0),
    x3 = case_when(
      x3 == 1 ~ 1,
      if_all(all_of(list), is.na) ~ NA_real_,
      TRUE ~ 0))
```

With `if_all()`, you don't even need to refer to the `list` variable, just pass a simple ***tidy-select*** helper instead, e.g.

- `if_all(x1:x2, is.na)` (This way `x1` & `x2` must be consecutive columns)
- `if_all(starts_with("x"), is.na)`
- `if_all(num_range("x", 1:2), is.na)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea. We can use `all_of`, `select` to select the columns based on the `target` vector (I changed `list` to `target` as `list` is a function in R), then use `is.na` and `rowSums` to evaluate if all columns are `NA`. We can combine this strategy with `case_when` to create the `x3` column.

```
library(dplyr)

target <- c("x1", "x2")

df3 %>%
  mutate(
    x3 = case_when(
      rowSums(is.na(select(., all_of(target)))) == 0               ~0L,
      rowSums(is.na(select(., all_of(target)))) != 0 & !is.na(x3)  ~1L,
      TRUE                                                         ~NA_integer_
    ), 
  )
# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#   x1    x2       x3
#   <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 Yes   Yes       0
# 2 No    Yes       0
# 3 NA    NA       NA
# 4 NA    NA        1
```